# Rhino Mock, Mocking a static call from a non-Mocked object

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino

Here my test code:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Delete_ShouldCancelLayoutView()
    {
        Expect.Call(TreeMasterService.Delete(1, null)).Return(null).IgnoreArguments();
        Mocks.ReplayAll();
        TestController.Delete(1);
    }
```

here is the Testee:

```
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        TreeMasterService.Delete(id, CurrentUser);
        CancelLayout();
        CancelView();
    }
```

Is there any way to make sure CancelLayout() and CancelView() is called with Rhino Mocks?

Answer (score 2):

No.
Free mocking frameworks like Rhino effectively create a transparent proxy for your Class under test. Therefore you can by design only operate on interface methods and virtual methods.
For stuff like the above you need either the [MS Moles](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/b3b41648-1c21-471f-a2b0-f76d8fb932ee) framework or a commercial tool like [Typemock](http://www.typemock.com).

HTH
Thomas